# BeautifulSoup4, как достать данные в ::before

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь собрать данные со [страницы](https://grodno.btrans.by/ostanovka)

Код

```
def get_stop(empty_url):
    sess = requests.Session()
    sess.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'
    response = sess.get(empty_url)
    global stop
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    for stop in soup.find_all("a", class_="stop-link"):
        stop = stop.text
    return print(stop)
```

Сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что итоговый список stop пустой, данные же находятся в таком формате [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно недокурил теории и чего-то не понимаю, методом проб успеха не принесло, как достать данные находящиеся либо в title="*", либо после тега ::before

Comment: Недокурили, print возвратит None из функции, а в stop будет последнее, перезаписанное в каждом шаге цикла, значение. Примените метод append() для списка.

Answer (score 0):

Смоделировал твою ситуацию. У тебя есть глобальная переменная stop (*не самая лучшая идея, но не мне судить*), подразумеваю, что это список.
Ты ее объявляешь в функции, а чуть ниже переопределяешь в цикле, причем заменяешь ее на нее же, но с атрибутом text.
Вот пример кода, который мне напечатал список всех остановок

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_stop(empty_url):
    sess = requests.Session()
    sess.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'
    response = sess.get(empty_url)
    global stop
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all("a", class_="stop-link"):
        stop.append(link.text) 
    return print(stop)

url = 'https://grodno.btrans.by/ostanovka'
stop = []
get_stop(url)
```